# How to count the date to make a list of events?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, calendar, codeigniter-2

I'm using Codeigniter V2.1.3 and I have a calendar template that have a scheduling stuff and I want to count the events in a particular date. Here is my database:

```
              ----Table: schedule -----
   id  | materialID  | borrowerID | date_reserve |
   ------------------------------------------------
   1   |     7       |     7      |  2013-08-16  |
   2   |     10      |     10     |  2013-08-16  |
   1   |     12      |     13     |  2013-08-18  |
```

What I want is in my calendar template the total event for the `date=2013-08-16` will be `2 events`. Here is my code which is not working coz it keeps on sending me only `1 event` maybe you could figure out where is my mistake in here:

```
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('schedule')->like('date_reserve', "$year-$month")->get();
    $cal_data = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $index = ltrim(substr($row->date_reserve,8,2), '0'); 
        $cal_data[$index] = count($row->borrowerID). 'event(s)';
    }
    return $cal_data;
```

Any help?

Comment: use SELECT COUNT(*) instead, if you want the result for the full date, supply the full date in where statement, otherwise if you want just the year & month your like statement should be something like '2013-08%' to match whatever day in that month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want number of events for exact date: YYYY-MM-DD you can replace like with where:

```
$r = $this->db->select('id, materialID, borrowerID, date_reserve')
              ->where('date_reverse', $year."-".$month."-".$day)
              ->get('schedule')
              ->result();
```

Also you can print_r the result so you will see what the result is. Also you can echo last query: `echo $this->db->last_query();`

**Edit:**
We had to run query per each date to fetch the number of events.

```
$cal_data = array();
    for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
    {
        $this->db->select('COUNT(id) as count,date_reserve,borrowerID');
    $this->db->from('schedule');    
    $this->db->where('date_reserve',"$year-$month-$i"); 
    //$this->db->group_by('date_reserve');    
    $query = $this->db->get();


    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $cal_data[$index] = $row->count. 'event(s)';
    }
```

Comment: How could i put that in my calendar template?

Comment: Just replace your query with this one. Then in foreach you will use `$r` as argument: `foreach($r as $row)`

Comment: Where did you get the $day?

Comment: Where did you get the $year ?

Comment: You need to set those variables from post data or however you want

Comment: Yes it is posted the `$year` and `$month`. Have you work with codeigniter calendar class before?

Comment: The problem is not with calendar but with your query. I made test table and run query: SELECT * FROM table WHERE date LIKE '%2013-08%' and I got all data.

Comment: Please do understand my question sir. I need to put the number of events on my calendar. Would you give me some time sir? would you mind https://chatstep.com/#leonard

Answer (score 0):

try using `group_by`

```
public function get_results($date) {   

    $this->db->select('COUNT(id),date_reserve');
    $this->db->from('schedule');

    $this->db->like('date_reserve',$date);

    $this->group_by('date_reserve');    
    $result = $this->db->get();

    return $result->result_array();

}
```

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza hmm now what is the problem are you facing ??

Comment: I couln't put it on my calendar template. It shows me `1 event` https://chatstep.com/#leonard would you mine to join me here sir?